# Hidden layer on top of iOS MAUI .NET 7.0

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Im having this problem where my iOS app deployed but there's like an invisible wall that's not letting me click anything(this is for iOS only). On android everything runs perfect nothing broken as far as I can see

here is the login page xaml:

```
<Grid Padding="0" VerticalOptions="Center" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto">
    <Image x:Name="ImageLogo" Source="rcm_white_red_transpar.png" VerticalOptions="Center"          WidthRequest="350" HeightRequest="104"/>
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" Padding="10">
        <Entry x:Name="PhoneNumber" Keyboard="Telephone" BackgroundColor="White"    Placeholder="Phone Number XXX-XXX-XXXX" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="320" TextColor="Black" PlaceholderColor="SlateGray"/>
        <Entry x:Name="PinNumber" Keyboard="Numeric" BackgroundColor="White" Placeholder="PIN Number XXXXXX" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="320" IsVisible="false" TextColor="Black" PlaceholderColor="SlateGray"/>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonSignIn" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="320" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" Text="Sign In" Clicked="ButtonSignIn_Clicked" IsVisible="false" />
        <Button x:Name="ButtonSendCode" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="320" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" Text="Send PIN" Clicked="ButtonSendCode_Clicked" IsVisible="true" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
        
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator Color="{StaticResource Primary}" x:Name="LoginActivityIndicator" IsRunning="False"/>
</Grid>
```

here's the login page xaml.cs:

```
string logout_message_ = null;
public string logout_message
{
    set
    {
        logout_message_ = value;
    }
}

public LoginPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();
    http_client_ = App.GetBackendClient();

    // In the accept header value, we tell that JSON is an acceptable response type.
    http_client_.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // load our last phone number used
    var task = SecureStorage.GetAsync("last_phone_number");
    task.Wait();
    var token = task.Result;
    if (token != null)
    {
        PhoneNumber.Text = token;
    }
}

//Override the OnAppearing function to load our MSAL
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    //Disable the Flyout so user's cant get in unwarranted
    Shell.Current.FlyoutBehavior = FlyoutBehavior.Disabled;
    //show activity
    LoginActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;

    if (logout_message_ != null)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Logged Out", logout_message_, "Dismiss");
    }

    //Authenticate
    try
    {
        var oauthToken = await App.GetCachedLogin();
        if (oauthToken != null)
        {
            await App.Login(oauthToken);
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(HomePage)}");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Do nothing - the user isn't logged in
        await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Dismiss");
    }
    LoginActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
    base.OnAppearing();
}

//Override the OnDisappearing function to enable the Flyout when leaving
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    Shell.Current.FlyoutBehavior = FlyoutBehavior.Flyout;
    LoginActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
    base.OnDisappearing();
}

//Button Send Code Command in LoginPage.xaml
private async void ButtonSendCode_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string phone_number = RemoveNonNumeric(PhoneNumber.Text);
    string requestUri = "api/Login/start/" + phone_number + "/" + Constants.LoginSecretKey;

    try
    {
        //send api call to backend
        //if successful then unhide other buttons
        HttpResponseMessage response = await http_client_.GetAsync(requestUri);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            ButtonSignIn.IsVisible = true;
            PinNumber.IsVisible = true;
            ButtonSendCode.Text = "Resend PIN";
            // We generate a request and read the content asynchronously
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else if (response.StatusCode == (System.Net.HttpStatusCode)429)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Too many pin requests. Please wait before trying again.", "Dismiss");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", (int)response.StatusCode + ": " + response.ReasonPhrase, "Dismiss");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("An error has occurred", ex.Message, "Dismiss");
    }
}

private async void ButtonSignIn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string phone_number = RemoveNonNumeric(PhoneNumber.Text);
    string user_pin = PinNumber.Text;
    string requestUri = "api/Login/finish/" + phone_number + "/" + user_pin;

    try
    {
        // need to call the phone login finish API and if successful with a token returned the login
        HttpResponseMessage response = await http_client_.GetAsync(requestUri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // We generate a request and read the content asynchronously
            var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            await App.Login(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(token));

            // save the last valid phone login for use on future launches
            await SecureStorage.SetAsync("last_phone_number", PhoneNumber.Text);
            PinNumber.Text = "";// clear our pin

            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(HomePage)}");
        }
        else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Incorrect pin or phone number.", "Dismiss");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", (int)response.StatusCode + ": " + response.ReasonPhrase, "Dismiss");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        await DisplayAlert("An error has occurred", ex.Message, "Dismiss");
    }
}

public static string RemoveNonNumeric(string text)
{
    string newText = "";
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return newText;
    }
    newText = Regex.Replace(text, "[^0-9]", "");

    return newText;
}
```

Here's the app shell too if its helpful:

```
<!--
    The overall app visual hierarchy is defined here, along with navigation.    
    https://docs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/
-->
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemRobotModeOff">
            <Label x:Name="LabelRobotMode"
                   Text="Robot Mode OFF"
                   IsVisible="false"
                   HeightRequest="40"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="Large"
                   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemRobotModeOn">
            <Label Text="Robot Mode ON"
                   HeightRequest="40"
                   IsVisible="false"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="Large"
                   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Active}"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
        <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
        <!--
        Default Styles for all Flyout Items
        https://docs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyoutitem-and-menuitem-style-classes
        -->
        <Style Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"></Setter>
            <!-- Change font for FlyoutItem to Custom Font -->
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="DINOTMedium.otf#DINOTMedium.otf"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextTransform" Value="Uppercase"/>
        </Style>
        <Style Class="FlyoutItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{x:OnPlatform iOS={AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource Accent}, Light={StaticResource Secondary},Default={StaticResource Accent}}, Android={AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource Accent}, Light={StaticResource Secondary},Default={StaticResource Accent}}}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <!--Custom Style you can apply to any Flyout Item-->
        <Style Class="MenuItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" >
            <!--ApplyToDerivedTypes="True"-->
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <!--Custom Style for Robot Mode menu item -->
        <Style Class="MenuItemRobotModeOnStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Active}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style Class="MenuItemRobotModeOffStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>
<!--Default login Page-->
<ShellItem Route="Login">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"/>
</ShellItem>
<!--
    When the Flyout is visible this defines the content to display in the flyout.
    FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" will create a separate flyout item for each child element    
    https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.shellgroupitem.flyoutdisplayoptions?view=xamarin-forms
-->

<FlyoutItem x:Name="HomePage" Title="Home" Icon="{AppThemeBinding Dark=home_white.png,Light=home.png}">
    <Tab>
    <ShellContent Route="HomePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"/>
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
 <FlyoutItem x:Name="MowersPage" Title="Machines" Icon="{AppThemeBinding Dark=machine_white.png,Light=machine.png}">
    <ShellContent Route="MowersPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MowersPage}"/>
</FlyoutItem> 

<FlyoutItem x:Name="PlanPage" Title="Plan" Icon="{AppThemeBinding Dark=plan_white.png,Light=plan.png}">
    <ShellContent Route="PlanPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PlanPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem x:Name="MonitorPage" Title="Monitor" Icon="{AppThemeBinding Dark=monitor_white.png,Light=monitor.png}">
    <ShellContent Route="MonitorPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MonitorPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem x:Name="MowPage" Title="Mow" Icon="{AppThemeBinding Dark=mow_white.png,Light=mow.png}">
    <ShellContent Route="MowPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MowPage}"/>
</FlyoutItem>

<!-- When the Flyout is visible this will be a menu item you can tie a click behavior to  -->
<MenuItem x:Name="LogoutMenuItem" Text="Logout" StyleClass="MenuItemLayoutStyle" Clicked="OnMenuItemLogout_Clicked" />
<!--
    TabBar lets you define content that won't show up in a flyout menu. When this content is active
    the flyout menu won't be available. This is useful for creating areas of the application where 
    you don't want users to be able to navigate away from. If you would like to navigate to this 
    content you can do so by calling 
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPage");
-->
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
</TabBar>

<!-- Optional Templates 
// These may be provided inline as below or as separate classes.

// This header appears at the top of the Flyout.
// https://docs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-header
<Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>ContentHere</Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>

// ItemTemplate is for ShellItems as displayed in a Flyout
// https://docs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#define-flyoutitem-appearance
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentView>
            Bindable Properties: Title, Icon
        </ContentView>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>

// MenuItemTemplate is for MenuItems as displayed in a Flyout
// https://docs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#define-menuitem-appearance
<Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentView>
            Bindable Properties: Text, Icon
        </ContentView>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
-->
<Shell.FlyoutFooter>
    <StackLayout>
        <Image x:Name="CustomerSupportImage" Source="{AppThemeBinding Dark={OnPlatform iOS=rcm_badge_horiz_cust_supp_phone.png, Android=Images/rcm_badge_horiz_cust_supp_phone.png}, Light={OnPlatform iOS=rcm_badge_horiz_cust_supp_phone_invert.png, Android=Images/rcm_badge_horiz_cust_supp_phone_invert.png},Default={OnPlatform iOS=rcm_badge_horiz_cust_supp_phone.png, Android=Images/rcm_badge_horiz_cust_supp_phone.png}}" WidthRequest="250" />
        <Image Source="{AppThemeBinding Dark={OnPlatform iOS=rcm_white_red_transpar.png, Android=Images/rcm_white_red_transpar.png}, Light={OnPlatform iOS=rcm_black_red_transpar.png, Android=Images/rcm_black_red_transpar.png},Default={OnPlatform iOS=rcm_white_red_transpar.png, Android=Images/rcm_white_red_transpar.png}}" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" Margin="20"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Shell.FlyoutFooter>
```

I tried downloading vs on my Mac book to see if the problem was with the simulator and no luck. I even tried it on my iPhone and the invisible wall is still present

Comment: It's really difficult to read your XAML. I'd recommend formatting it and placing the different attributes on separate lines. Also, that's an awful lot of code in the code-behind file. I'd recommend using the MVVM pattern. One thing I noticed is that you're using a `Grid` to stack elements in z, with an `ActivityIndicator` all the way in the front. When that's not running, it should be invisible. Can you try and see if your page works on iOS without the `ActivityIndicator`?

Comment: @ewerspej removing that ActivityIndicator worked!

Comment: Yes, because it was covering the other `VisualElement`s. You should consider switching to the MVVM pattern (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm), move your business logic into a ViewModel and use bindings instead of manipulating Views from the code behind. Make sure that the `ActivityIndicator` is only visible when it's running.

Comment: FWIW: With respect to this question, the solution in the above comment is **Make sure that the ActivityIndicator is only visible when it's running.**  Everything else is a recommendation about how to structure code. I think it would be better to emphasize the solution, keep other suggestions separate. Or omit them: user didn't ask for code structuring suggestions. Goal is to have focused Q&A's on specific technical questions.

Comment: You could set a BackgroundColor for ActivityIndicator to see if it covers any other controls. If the button is covered, of course we are not able to click it.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, you could set a background to see if ActivityIndicator covers other control. For covered control, you could not access it by clicking it.

An workaround is to set the IsVisible property. When ActivityIndicator is running set IsVisible to True. When ActivityIndicator is stopped set IsVisible to False.

```
LoginActivityIndicator.IsVisible = LoginActivityIndicator.IsRunning;
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently facing this issue, and have found a bug with Grids in Maui, specifically on iOS that prevents inputs.
[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6292)

Which is ironic since the only other way to create a decent layout is to use the now deprecated StackLayout.

If anyone has a workaround for this (Until the bug is fixed) that **doesn't** use deprecated code, I'm sure everybody will be grateful.

As a side note, this can be recreated with something as simple as the following Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Entry Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="What"/>
</Grid>
```